# jquery chosen select add vertical scrollbar on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

I'm using [chosen](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) SELECT (v.1.6.2) and one of my selects is the Country Select. I found out that there is a different behavior on mobile devices, but in my case I need the same behavior like on desktops, so I found in chosen.jquery.js file the code detecting mobiles around line 546 and commented `return false` like below:

```
 AbstractChosen.browser_is_supported = function() {
    if ("Microsoft Internet Explorer" === window.navigator.appName) {
      return document.documentMode >= 8;
    }
    if (/iP(od|hone)/i.test(window.navigator.userAgent) || /IEMobile/i.test(window.navigator.userAgent) || /Windows Phone/i.test(window.navigator.userAgent) || /BlackBerry/i.test(window.navigator.userAgent) || /BB10/i.test(window.navigator.userAgent) || /Android.*Mobile/i.test(window.navigator.userAgent)) {
      //return false;  <---- HERE
    }
    return true;
  };
```

but then I found out that there is no vertical scrollbar (which it's shown fine on desktop version) and I can't scroll the options with a finger, how to fix it on mobile? (I have also input element for filtering and this works fine).

Maybe I would stay with the mobile version, but then my own styles for chosen select are gone, so that's way I prefer to have desktop functionality on the mobile devices.

Comment: Also, if the scroll still doesnt work on touch devices you have to comment: `return evt.preventDefault();` from `this.container.bind('touchstart.chosen', function(evt) {` like this `this.container.bind('touchstart.chosen', function(evt) {
_this.container_mousedown(evt);
// return evt.preventDefault();
});`, **line 651**. I have found the fix at link [link](https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/issues/2597)